# How to know which exception type to catch, given the traceback?

Tags: python, exception, types

A general exception catcher logs the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "4sq.py", line 37, in <module>
    checkin = client.checkins()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/foursquare-20120716-py2.7.egg/foursquare/__init__.py", line 416, in __call__
    return self.GET('{CHECKIN_ID}'.format(CHECKIN_ID=CHECKIN_ID), params, multi=multi)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/foursquare-20120716-py2.7.egg/foursquare/__init__.py", line 217, in GET
    return self.requester.GET(self._expanded_path(path), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/foursquare-20120716-py2.7.egg/foursquare/__init__.py", line 163, in GET
    return self._request(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/foursquare-20120716-py2.7.egg/foursquare/__init__.py", line 200, in _request
    return _request_with_retry(url, data)['response']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/foursquare-20120716-py2.7.egg/foursquare/__init__.py", line 696, in _request_with_retry
    return _process_request_with_httplib2(url, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/foursquare-20120716-py2.7.egg/foursquare/__init__.py", line 719, in _process_request_with_httplib2
    return _check_response(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/foursquare-20120716-py2.7.egg/foursquare/__init__.py", line 742, in _check_response
    raise exc(meta.get('errorDetail'))
RateLimitExceeded: Quota exceeded
```

I would like to know the specific exception name so I could add a dedicated catch to it.
How can it be found?

Is there a 'type' function on the caught exception or should it be found in the throwing lib's source (available [here](https://github.com/mLewisLogic/foursquare/blob/master/foursquare/__init__.py.))?

Comment: Looks like it's a `RateLimitExceeded` exception. Though, to be sure, I would wrap it in a `try`/`except Exception as e` and print `e.__class__`. That'll give you a definite answer

Comment: Thanks was looking for something like the e.__class__ !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception being raised in the paste is `foursquare.RateLimitExceeded` (as it says in the final line).  You should be able to catch it as normal, or catch its base class `foursquare.FoursquareException` if you want to handle all errors from the module.

The code that raises the exception is just looking up which exception class to raise from a dictionary.  That shouldn't have any effect on how you catch those errors.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it's a `RateLimitExceeded` exception. Though, if you really want to be sure, you could do this:

```
try:
    # code
except Exception as e:
    print e.__class__
```

This would print out the exception class that was raised, which will give you a definitive answer