# catching error 60 ( timeout ) with urllib 2

Tags: python

I'm trying to catch error 60 and continue the execution of my script, here is what I am doing at the moment :

```
import urllib2
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


matcher = csv.reader(open('matcher.csv', "rb" ))

for i in matcher:
    url = i[1]
    if len(list(url)) > 0:
        print url
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url,timeout=10))   

        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            print ("There was an error: %r" % e)
```

It returns this :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "debug.py", line 13, in
>   
>       soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url,timeout=10))    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 126, in urlopen
>       return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 400, in open
>       response = self._open(req, data)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 418, in _open
>       '_open', req)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 378, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 1207, in http_open
>       return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 1180, in do_open
>       r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py",
>   line 1030, in getresponse
>       response.begin()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py",
>   line 407, in begin
>       version, status, reason = self._read_status()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py",
>   line 365, in _read_status
>       line = self.fp.readline()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py",
>   line 447, in readline
>       data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize) socket.timeout: timed out

How would I catch this error and "continue" ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13275029/198633)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `except Exception as e:` to catch all errors. However remember this catches all errors and should be avoided if you want to catch only specific errors.

**Edit:**
you can check the exception type by doing:

```
except Exception as e:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]      
    print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could import the exception object and modify your `except` block:

```
import socket

try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url,timeout=10))   

except urllib2.URLError as e:
    print ("There was an error: %r" % e)
except socket.timeout as e: # <-------- this block here
    print "We timed out"
```

**update**: Well, learnt something new - just found a reference to a `.reason` property:

```
except urllib2.URLError as e:
    if isinstance(e.reason, socket.timeout):
        pass # ignore this one
    else:
        # do stuff re other errors if you can...
        raise # otherwise propagate the error
```